# FactoryGirl: avoid creating multiple model instances for a 1-Model Unit Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

Rails 3.2.13, FactoryGirl, minitest-spec-rails.

I want to define a Factory for the `InvoicedItem` model. This `InvoicedItem` belongs to a (polymorphic) `:owner`. This `owner` can be a `SpentItem`. In order to create a `SpentItem`, I need to create several other records (`PricingGroup`, `PriceRatio`, `Supplier`, etc. etc.) This quickly becomes a nightmare.

Is there a way to define an association in FactoryGirl that does not use an existing model?

Basically, I don't want to have to instanciate several `SpentItem` related models to test `InvoicedItem`. I just need that the `owner` of InvoicedItem responds to the following methods: `name_for_invoice` and `bill_price_for_invoice`.

Currently, I have this:

require 'test_helper'

```
class FakeInvoicedItemOwner
  attr_accessor :name_for_invoice, :bill_price_for_invoice
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory 'FakeInvoicedItemOwner' do
    name_for_invoice { 'Fake Name' }
    bill_price_for_invoice { 12.0 }
  end

  factory 'Invoicing::InvoicedItem' do
    association :invoice, factory: 'Invoicing::Invoice'
    owner { FactoryGirl.build('FakeInvoicedItemOwner') }
    name { 'FG name' }
    billed_price { 1.0 }
  end
end
```

I always get a persistence-related error: `undefined method 'primary_key' for FakeInvoicedItemOwner:Class`

Because FactoryGirl is trying to persist this `FakeInvoicedItemOwner` instance, but I am trying to avoid that. Is there a way to tell FactoryGirl to use a fake object instead of giving a real Model factory?

**EDIT: Solution**

(naming is wrong, `Plus::SpentItemStub` should probably be `Invoicing::Stubs::SpentItem`)

```
# class inheriting from an invoice-able item
# redefines the methods used for Invoicing
class Plus::SpentItemStub < Plus::SpentItem
  def name_for_invoice
    'fake name for invoicing'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  # factory for my fake model above
  factory 'Plus::SpentItemStub' do
  end

  factory 'Invoicing::InvoicedItem' do
    # relation owner using a stubbed instance of my fake model
    owner { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed('Plus::SpentItemStub') }
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use the real models for each relationship but use `build_stubbed` rather then `build` which should be faster and lighter weight:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw this post about build_stubbed method of FactoryGirl and tried to find another way (the principal reason is the following: why would the Invoicing module factories should have to care about creating (with factories) items that can be invoiced). In the end, I used the build_stubbed method as you suggested, so thank you for this input!